# How to identify child grid filters column name in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have applied filter in child grid, but not identify child grid filter or main grid filter.

```
var childGrid = $(#ParentGird).closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
    childGrid..dataSource.filter({});
```

Comment: I am doing this exact thing in one of my projects, can you show me your code so that I can help you

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors in your code, e.g.: `$(#ParentGird)` shoud be `$("#ParentGird") ` and you have an extra dot in `childGrid..dataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

In this example below what I need to do with my child item is pass up a list of objects to the controller for validations so I am looping through my rows, getting the child grid, and then getting the child of my grid and then looping through those lines too and then adding them to an array.

This works well for me and what I need and is used in a number of places.

If you need any more help please edit your question and let me know what you need

This is my grid with child grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OrderLineViewModel>()
        .Name("DispatchedGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.OrderLineID).Visible(false);
            columns.Bound(e => e.OrderDispatchID).Visible(false);
            columns.Bound(o => o.OrderLineDispatchID).Visible(false);
            columns.Bound(e => e.OrderLineNo);
            columns.Bound(e => e.ProductCode);
            columns.Bound(e => e.ProductItemNumber);
            columns.Bound(e => e.ProductDescription);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Quantity);

        }).NoRecords("Blank Dispatch - Back Order")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(6)
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetOrderLines", "Dispatch"))
    )
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("fe_dispatch.dataBoundDispatch"))
)

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OrderLineDispatchViewModel>()
              .Name("grid_#=OrderLineID#") // template expression, to be evaluated in the master context
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Visible(false);
                  columns.Bound(o => o.OrderLineID).Visible(false);
                  columns.Bound(o => o.BoxQuantity).Visible(false);
                  columns.Bound(o => o.LotNumber).Width(200);
                  columns.Bound(o => o.InventoryQuantity);
                  columns.Bound(o => o.Bin).Width(200);
                  columns.Bound(o => o.DispatchedQuantity).Width(100); // If Qty = 0 then need to have a spinner here that will allow for bin selection.
              })
              .Editable(m => m.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .PageSize(10)
                  .Read(read => read.Action("GetOrderDispatchLines", "Dispatch", new { orderLineId = "#=OrderLineID#", dispatchId = "#=OrderDispatchID#" }))
                  .Model(model =>
                  {
                      model.Id(l => l.OrderLineID);
                      model.Field(p => p.DispatchedQuantity).Editable(true);
                      model.Field(p => p.LotNumber).Editable(false);
                      model.Field(p => p.InventoryQuantity).Editable(false);
                      model.Field(p => p.Bin).Editable(false);
                  })
              )
              .ToClientTemplate())
```

Then in the TypeScript behind this is whats inside my method (trimmed down for what you need)

```
var parentGrid: kendo.ui.Grid = $("#DispatchGrid").data("kendoGrid") as any;
var gridDataRow = parentGrid.dataSource.data();

 $.each(gridDataRow,
            (index, pItem) => {
                var childGrid: kendo.ui.Grid = $("#grid_" + pItem.OrderLineID).data("kendoGrid") as any;
                $.each(childGrid.dataSource.data(),
                    (index, cItem) => {
                        if (cItem.DispatchQuantity < 0) {


                        console.log(cItem);
                        dispatchItems.push({
                            OrderID: pItem.OrderID,
                            PickId: pickId,
                            OrderLineID: pItem.OrderLineID,
                            OrderLineNo: pItem.OrderLineNo,
                            ProductCode: pItem.ProductCode,
                            BoxQuantity: pItem.BoxQuantity,
                            ProductItemNumber: pItem.ProductItemNumber,
                            Description: pItem.ProductDescription,
                            LotNumber: cItem.LotNumber,
                            InventoryQuantity: cItem.InventoryQuantity,
                            Bin: cItem.Bin,
                            Quantity: cItem.DispatchQuantity,
                        });
                    });
            });
```